# How to make word autocorrect English even the Mac is set to be French

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, spell-check, input-languages

I recently changed the language setting of my MacBook Pro 15 inch to French (Canada). One of the unexpected consequences is when I type my stuff in Microsoft Word, the autocorrect function highlights pretty much everything I type.

I wonder if there is a workaround for this? Can I set autocorrect include both English and French? Or just set autocorrect to English since that is the language I mainly use in Microsoft Word?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Changing the language Mac OS X uses for spelling.

Within Mac OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks) and above you should be able to change the spelling language to be independent of the overall system language by going to “System Preferences… -> Keyboard” and then in that panel, select “Text” and within that panel you should see a “Spelling:” pulldown near the right-hand side of the panel that looks like this:

[image]

The default is “Automatic by Language”—which causes the behavior you are experiencing—so just change that value to be whichever flavor of English you prefer to use.

Not too sure about newer versions of Mac OS X, but it seems you can only choose one language for spelling in Mac OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks).

#### Changing the language Microsoft Word uses for spelling.

And while this is only connected to spell checking within Word, according to Microsoft themselves, you can set the “proofing language” independently of the whole system by [following these instructions](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Check-spelling-and-grammar-in-a-different-language-487fc9ba-a1b4-4911-8fd4-1f5b3e1841f2#bmword):

> To set the proofing language for text and check your spelling in your
>   document, do the following:
>
> 1. Select the text that you wants to check.
> 2. On the **Review** tab, in the **Language** group, click **Language**, and the click **Set Proofing Language Word Ribbon Language** button.
>
> [image]
>
> 3. In the **Language** dialog box, verify that the correct language is associated with the text. If it is not, select the language that you
>      want to use for the dictionary and other proofing tools.
>
>    If the language is preceded by the **Spelling & Grammar** icon, it
>      means that proofing tools, such as spelling checker, are installed for
>      that language. If the language is not preceded by the **Spelling &
>      Grammar** icon, the dictionary for that language is not available and
>      you cannot check the spelling and grammar for that language.
> 4. Complete steps 1-3 for each section of text that is in a different language.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, even in yosemite the mac still only allows one spelling check, but it is much better than the previous case. Thank you very much